# How can i get 'y' rather than 'yhat' from predicted data by using fbprophet?

Tags: python, facebook

I can use fbprophet (in python) to get some predicted data, but it just includes 't', 'yhat', 'yhat_upper', 'yhat_lower' and or so rather than 'y' which I also want to acquire.

At present I think I can't get the value of 'y' from the predicted data because Prophet doesn't work for predicting the future value like 'y'.

Am I predicting by a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, 'y' is the data you're using yo fit with, i.e. the input to prophet. 'yhat' is the mean(or median?) of the predicted distribution.

Comment: 'y' is history data and the input to propeht,and similary I also want to get 'y' from the predicted data

Answer (score 0):

I am using below snippet for that. A bit silly but easy way to handle your question.

```
m = Prophet(weekly_seasonality=True,
                yearly_seasonality=True,
                daily_seasonality=True,
                interval_width=0.95,
                holidays=holiday_df)

m.add_seasonality(name='monthly', period=30.5, fourier_order=5)
m.fit(train_df)

future_df = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=len(test_df))
future_forecast = m.predict(future_df)

y = train_df['y'].append(test_df['y']).reset_index(drop=True)
future_forecast = future_forecast.join(y)
```